# How to change ruby current version by using Capistrano?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

We are using ruby version 1.8.7 in our staging server but we need to have ruby 2.4.0 to install rails 5.0. We have installed both versions of ruby, i.e., ruby 1.8.7 and 2.4.0 by RVM through Capistrano.

We have tried to change the ruby version from 1.8.7 to 2.4.0 to install rails 5.0.
But the problem is the ruby version does not change to 2.4.0.

Capistrano version: 2.15.4.

What do we need to do to change the ruby version to 2.4.0 and install Rails 5.0 in staging by Capistrano?

Comment: Did you try setting the default ruby to 2.4.0 in RVM?

Comment: No, already one application runs under ruby 1.8.7, so we are not setting the default ruby to 2.4.0.

Comment: Did you add the ruby version in Gem file? I assume you did not add, I hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: Did you try `set :rvm_ruby_version, '2.4.0'` in `config/deploy.rb` file?